# view sql produced by crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects, time-and-attendance

I am developing reports for a system using **Workforce Time and Attendance**.  The system uses an Oracle database, Crystal Reports, and (I think) Business Objects.  My reports use parameters.  I want to know how those parameters are being used.  Is there a way to see the actual SQL that's being sent to the database server?

Please don't respond with **Database | Show SQL Query...**  That shows me the SQL I created (with the parameter names).  I want to see what the database server is receiving.

Comment: I think you can find that sql query in MSSMS under Activity Monitor

Comment: What's MSSMS?  Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio?  I don't see how that's related.

Comment: you can see the queries there

Comment: @PeterKsenak OP uses Oracle, not SQL Server.

Comment: @dougp Basically the idea of Peter Ksenak isn't completely wrong, just the tools he mentioned...You should be able to monitor the query, maybe like mentioned here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/8828/how-do-you-show-sql-executing-on-an-oracle-database